# How to add this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello StackOverflow community,
i have a slideshow that i want to insert to my website
but its kinda complicated because its only the javascript files
you can test it here or download it

```
http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/
```

i have had other slideshows under this code cause it was clear and easy to understand

Here's an image of the folder contents!
http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/2076/zekw.png

can anybody tell me how to add it to the website?
Thanks so much

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: read the following file : `README` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create this HTML

```
<ul class="your_class">
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

include JS file with this plugin and init function like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.your_class').roundabout();
});
```

Comment: there's two java scripts which one?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.roundabout.min.js"></script>
or
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.roundabout.js"></script>

Comment: `jquery.roundabout.js` for local testing, and the `minified` version for production/live.

Comment: you must include 2 files: 1) jQuery libriry 2) plugin library. Init function can be place in your HTML or in any JS file.